# Changing/Spoofing MAC Address/Physical Address 

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

The only method i know is via adding "NetworkAddress" key/value pair in nic's Registry.
It's too difficult for me to implement via this method.
Is there another method ?

I built a sample application using Windows Forms but the setMac method needs Implementation
http://pastebin.com/umgxAWJU

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the MAC address permanently, or only for a given network conversation?

Comment: not permanent but as long as the user wishes to do so

Answer (score 2):

You can't spoof MAC addresses via .net directly as it does not have an API to that low a level of the network stack.  There is a library called [Pcap.net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) that is a wrapper for a native library that allows you to do this called [winPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/)

Comment: I have a visual c function from an legacy app but unfortunately im having a hard time understanding it 
http://pastebin.com/ePMx30CB